# Facebook Callback appends '#_=_' to Return URL

Tags: facebook, returnurl

Facebook callback has started appending `#_=_` hash underscore to the Return URL

Does anyone know why? What is the solution?

Comment: I'm also facing with same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7190184/912011 However, I think it may be related with Firefox release.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this problem? The standard facebook connect sdk does not work.

Comment: The best we can do until Facebook corrects this bug (or their documentation) is in my answer below.  First, set up your login urls in accordance with their documentation.  And second, add a quick header javascript hack to avoid this in your code.  This will degrade well if Facebook ever fixes this.

Comment: Irritating FB API bug. It brakes my AJAX navigation :(

Comment: Any idea **how** facebook appends these characters? Facebook redirects to my handler where I then handle the redirection to the return url, yet the characters are still appended to the url.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318390728250352/ This link might make you laugh

Comment: @BenFoster I think you'll find if you use Fiddler or similar that when FB redurects to your handler, the `#_=_` is in place, then even though you do a `Response.Redirect` to where you actually want to do, **the browser maintains the hash**, which is why it's only the *client-side* workarounds suggested below that will work.

Comment: I have yet to find an answer as to *why* this is being appended. The included Facebook posts in this thread aren't helpful.

Comment: Anyone know why I am getting this and NOTHING else.

Comment: 2016 March, still happening :P

Comment: April 2016 still happening. -_-

Comment: May 2016 still happening :-)

Comment: FYI, it [will not be fixed](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318390728250352)

Comment: 2017, what the zuck

Comment: May 2017, still....

Comment: June 2017 :) still happening. #_=_

Comment: July 2017... yada yada yada

Comment: August 2017 same shit

Comment: November 2017, nothing's change ..

Comment: December 2017, STILL HAPPENING

Comment: Welcome to 2018! Yep.. still happening.

Comment: February 2018, bug still happening...

Comment: March 2018..yep still happening

Comment: 31st May 2018.., #_=_ FTW!

Comment: July 27th, 2018. It is still happening!

Comment: 1 August 2018 still happening! :(

Comment: 29 September 2018... Grrr

Comment: October 2018 still happening :(

Comment: Jan 2019 still happening

Comment: April 2019 still happening :)

Comment: August 2019, no news on this issue  x)

Comment: April 2020 and I still see it

Comment: Christmas 2020 still happening :(

Comment: February 2021 is still a problem for me

Comment: April 2021, v10.0 still happening

Comment: To me this actual seems like a browser bug, because the #_=_ comes from the first redirect, but the second redirect doesn't have a hash, so it seems like a vulnerability that the hash given in a set of redirect is kept even on further redirects (so long as the last one doesn't have a hash)..

Comment: February 2022, still happening! <(^.^<)

Comment: Found you in September 2022.. because why dis happening?

Comment: 2023, still happening!

Answer (score 246):

via [Facebook's Platform Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/):

> Change in Session Redirect Behavior
>
> This week, we started adding a fragment #____=____ to the redirect_uri when
>   this field is left blank. Please ensure that your app can handle this
>   behavior.

To prevent this, set the redirect_uri in your login url request like so: (using Facebook php-sdk)

```php
$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'],'scope' => 'user_about_me'));
```

**UPDATE**

The above is exactly as the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/) says to fix this.  However, Facebook's documented solution does not work.  Please consider leaving a comment on the [Facebook Platform Updates blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/) and follow [this bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/196125357123225) to get a better answer.  Until then, add the following to your head tag to resolve this issue:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
        window.location.hash = '';
    }
</script>
```

Or a more detailed alternative (thanks [niftylettuce](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/12#issuecomment-5913711)):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
        if (window.history && history.pushState) {
            window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
        } else {
            // Prevent scrolling by storing the page's current scroll offset
            var scroll = {
                top: document.body.scrollTop,
                left: document.body.scrollLeft
            };
            window.location.hash = '';
            // Restore the scroll offset, should be flicker free
            document.body.scrollTop = scroll.top;
            document.body.scrollLeft = scroll.left;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm having issues with this too, using Java though, but the hash thing is in the way nonetheless.

Comment: what field is left blank? This is very cryptic

Comment: Agreed.  If you're having this problem, please comment on the Facebook Platform Update: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/

Comment: @Ryan Update almost works for me, I still get a hash (/#) on the end. Not happy with FB.

Comment: I still get the /# as well. anyone update here? to get the # removed

Comment: This solution will erase the hash:
<script type="text/javascript">
        var idx=window.location.toString().indexOf("#_=_");
        if (idx>0) {
            window.location = window.location.toString().substring(0, idx);
        }
    </script>

Just be sure this to be the first tag in the head element.

Comment: what does this refer to: "when this field is left blank" ... what 'field'?

Comment: typical facebook documentation.

Comment: This link is broken. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/196125357123225 Does anyone have the updated bug link? I'd like to see the status of this issue in the facebook api

Comment: I noticed your bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1424488987806270/ I also tried my hand at searching "fragment request_uri" with the same results.

Comment: Hey, @niftylettuce here, can you please update your answer to this? https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/12#issuecomment-40427410

Comment: Why is this being appended? The Facebook documentation doesn't say.

Comment: I think this solution DOES work. You just need to use the `https` protocol in your callback URL.

Comment: As @GorgiRankovski cited above, this works perfectly, just ensure it's the FIRST script that runs in the HEAD element. Same is true for PapaSierra's solution below.

Comment: Only to complete this discussion: Facebook also explains, why they added this anchor - go to: [https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318390728250352/](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318390728250352/)

Comment: that will leave the # sign :(

Comment: @Ryan I tried this solution which seems to be point at right direction but the redirect does not work for me. It also redirect to /#_=_. What could I be missing? I am asking in terms of the original answer (not the update). Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @GorgiRankovski, your solution worked best as it removes the final hash.

Comment: @Ryan if there's a search string in the initial url, it will be gone. I would just add append window.location.search here: `window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);`

Answer (score 125):

**TL;DR**

```js
if (window.location.hash === "#_=_"){
    history.replaceState 
        ? history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href.split("#")[0])
        : window.location.hash = "";
}
```

**Full version with step by step instructions**

```js
// Test for the ugliness.
if (window.location.hash === "#_=_"){

    // Check if the browser supports history.replaceState.
    if (history.replaceState) {

        // Keep the exact URL up to the hash.
        var cleanHref = window.location.href.split("#")[0];

        // Replace the URL in the address bar without messing with the back button.
        history.replaceState(null, null, cleanHref);

    } else {

        // Well, you're on an old browser, we can get rid of the _=_ but not the #.
        window.location.hash = "";

    }

}
```

Step by step:

1. We'll only get into the code block if the `fragment` is `#_=_`.
2. Check if the browser supports the HTML5 `window.replaceState` method.

   1. Clean the URL by splitting on `#` and taking only the first part.
   2. Tell `history` to replace the current page state with the clean URL. This modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one. What this means is the back and forward buttons will work just the way you want. ;-)
3. If the browser does not support the awesome HTML 5 history methods then just clean up the URL as best you can by setting the hash to empty string. This is a poor fallback because it still leaves a trailing hash (example.com/#) and also it adds a history entry, so the back button will take you back to `#_-_`.

Learn more about [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method).

Learn more about [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Properties).

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too. The other solution gets rid of any query parameters.

Comment: It does the same thing for google omniauth, so I get an error no route matches, it appends # (hashtag) after request uri https://.....herokua‌​pp.com/auth/google_oa‌​uth2/callback?state=1‌​9feaacfe23423jh5jhhGS‌​DFwb419049ebb18dabdf8‌​&code=4/glrY3-mSlTzwe‌​rwERTEG334eXcn3hOSxGu‌​c51BAlglPa4AU#

Comment: Worked for me better than the solution of @Ryan, as it does not delete the query.

Comment: This solution worked better than the Ryan's solution. I pass some parameters to the url after it goes thru facebook's authentication and Ryan's solution, for some reason just removes every parameter from the url. This solution works perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 68):

This was implemented by Facebook by design for security reasons. Here's the explanation from Eric Osgood, a Facebook Team member:

> This has been marked as 'by design'
>   because it prevents a potential security vulnerability.
>
> Some browsers will append the hash fragment from a URL to the end of a
>   new URL to which they have been redirected (if that new URL does not
>   itself have a hash fragment).
>
> For example if example1.com returns a redirect to example2.com, then a
>   browser going to example1.com#abc will go to example2.com#abc, and the
>   hash fragment content from example1.com would be accessible to a
>   script on example2.com.
>
> Since it is possible to have one auth flow redirect to another, it
>   would be possible to have sensitive auth data from one app accessible
>   to another.
>
> This is mitigated by appending a new hash fragment to the redirect URL
>   to prevent this browser behavior.
>
> If the aesthetics, or client-side behavior, of the resulting URL are
>   of concern, it would be possible to use window.location.hash (or even
>   a server-side redirect of your own) to remove the offending
>   characters.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318390728250352/

Comment: This is the only answer that actually explains why this happens, thanks, I think I'll leave the offending chars in my urls now that I know they're not an issue.

Comment: This is also implemented by Tumblr in their redirects. (as of mid-'19) Thanks for pointing to the FB explanation. Easily solved in a simplistic Passport app by merely pointing the successful redirect to "/#" instead of just "/" (which explains why I see more trailing octothorps on the web, I think...)

Comment: Well for people using vue router they're a big issue.. As it will crash because vue router is expecting a valid js selector which this isn't, they could have just set `#` with nothing else and the vulnerability would still be mitigated, but no they had to put some more weird stuff requiring dirty workarounds

Comment: This is so fat bs design it annoys me back and forth. If they want to use redirect_url parameter then allow us to pass query params for that purpose, otherwise the default behaviour will clear them

Answer (score 61):

if you want to remove the remaining "#" from the url

```js
$(window).on('load', function(e){
  if (window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
    window.location.hash = ''; // for older browsers, leaves a # behind
    history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname); // nice and clean
    e.preventDefault(); // no page reload
  }
})
```

Comment: $(window).on('load', function(e){ /*likebeats's code*/ } works.

Comment: i use this code by change e.preventDefault(); to event.preventDefault();

Comment: This code is assuming jQuery, and an onWindowReady event listener taking the argument `e`.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure why they're doing this but, you could get around this by reseting the hash at the top of your page:

```js
if (window.location.hash == "#_=_")
  window.location.hash = "";
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also specify your own hash on the `redirect_uri` parameter for the Facebook callback, which might be helpful in certain circumstances e.g. `/api/account/callback#home`. When you are redirected back, it'll at least be a hash that corresponds to a known route if you are using backbone.js or similar (not sure about jquery mobile).

Answer (score 8):

Major annoying, especially for apps that parse the URI and not just read the $_GET... Here's the hack I threw together... Enjoy!

```html
<html xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Get rid of the Facebook residue hash in the URI
        // Must be done in JS cuz hash only exists client-side
        // IE and Chrome version of the hack
        if (String(window.location.hash).substring(0,1) == "#") {
                window.location.hash = "";
                window.location.href=window.location.href.slice(0, -1);
                }
        // Firefox version of the hack
        if (String(location.hash).substring(0,1) == "#") {
                location.hash = "";
                location.href=location.href.substring(0,location.href.length-3);
                }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
URI should be clean
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be careful about making assumptions when parsing any data that you don't create. URI fragment identifiers were spec'd as early as RFC 1738 (in 1994) so if you use a correct URI parser, this should never be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

This can become kind of a serious issue if you're using a JS framework with hashbang (/#!/) URLs, e.g. Angular. Indeed, Angular will consider URLs with a non-hashbang fragment as invalid and throw an error :

```
Error: Invalid url "http://example.com/#_=_", missing hash prefix "#!".
```

If you're in such a case (and redirecting to your domain root), instead of doing :

```
window.location.hash = ''; // goes to /#, which is no better
```

Simply do :

```
window.location.hash = '!'; // goes to /#!, which allows Angular to take care of the rest
```

Comment: 1.2+ , this works awesome. For 1.0 and below use window.location.hash = '';

Comment: Yes, I only tested this on 1.2, thanks for the specification !

Comment: And then there is html5 mode

Answer (score 5):

I do not see how this problem is related to facebook AJAX. In fact the issue also occurs with JavaScript disabled and purely redirect based logins.

An example exchange with facebook:

```html
1. GET <https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&scope=email&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL> RESPONSE 302 Found Location: <https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?[...]>  
2. GET <https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?[...]> RESPONSE 302 Found MY_REDIRECT_URL?code=FB_CODE#_  
3. GET MY_REDIRECT_URL?code=FB_CODE#_
```

Happens only with Firefox for me too.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to my redirect page fixed the problem for me ...

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf('#_=_') > 0) {
    window.location = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/, '');
}
```

Comment: this causes a window location change, initiating a page refresh

Answer (score 3):

With angular and angular ui router, you can fix this

```
    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

      // Make a trailing slash optional for all routes
      // - Note: You'll need to specify all urls with a trailing slash if you use this method.
      $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
        /***
        Angular misbehaves when the URL contains a "#_=_" hash.

        From Facebook:
          Change in Session Redirect Behavior
          This week, we started adding a fragment #_=_ to the redirect_uri when this field is left blank.
          Please ensure that your app can handle this behavior.

        Fix:
          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url#answer-7297873
        ***/
        if ($location.hash() === '_=_'){
          $location.hash(null);
        }

        var path = $location.url();

        // check to see if the path already has a slash where it should be
        if (path[path.length - 1] === '/' || path.indexOf('/?') > -1) {
          return;
        }
        else if (path.indexOf('?') > -1) {
          $location.replace().path(path.replace('?', '/?'));
        }
        else {
          $location.replace().path(path + '/');
        }
      });

      // etc ...
    });
});
```

Comment: doesn't work here - the route changes before the rule() is applied

Answer (score 3):

If you're using vue-router, you can append to the list of routes:

```
{
  path: '/_=_',
  redirect: '/', // <-- or other default route
},
```

Answer (score 2):

A change was introduced recently in how Facebook handles session redirects. See "Change in Session Redirect Behavior" in this week's [Operation Developer Love](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/) blog post for the announcement.

Comment: I am not sure, what is he referring to here

Answer (score 2):

For me, i make JavaScript redirection to another page to get rid of `#_=_`. The ideas below should work. :)

```
function redirect($url){
    echo "<script>window.location.href='{$url}?{$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]}'</script>";        
}
```

Comment: this is not a good idea I think because you are creating multiple useless requests

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that worked for me (using Backbone.js), was to add "#/" to the end of the redirect URL passed to Facebook. Facebook will keep the provided fragment, and not append its own "_=_".

Upon return, Backbone will remove the "#/" part. For AngularJS, appending "#!" to the return URL should work.

Note that the fragment identifier of the original URL is preserved on redirection (via HTTP status codes 300, 301, 302 and 303) by most browsers, unless the redirect URL also has a fragment identifier. This [seems to be recommended behaviour](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Fragment/draft-bos-http-redirect-00.txt).

If you use a handler script that redirects the user elsewhere, you can append "#" to the redirect URL here to replace the fragment identifier with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I know this reply is late, but if you are using passportjs, you might want to see this.

```
return (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next();
};
```

I have written this middleware and applied it to express server instance, and the original URL I've got is without the `"#_=_"`. Looks like it when we apply passporJS' instance as middleware to the server instance, it doesn't take those characters, but are only visible on the address bar of our browsers.

Comment: "#_=_" it only available on the client. Review: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Answer (score 1):

I use this one, to delete '#' symbol as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
        window.location.href = window.location.href.split('#_=_')[0];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**For PHP SDK users**

I fixed the problem simply by removing the extra part before forwarding.

```
 $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);
 $loginURL = str_replace("#_=_", "", $loginURL);
 header("Location: " . $loginURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would remove the appended characters to your url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var idx=window.location.toString().indexOf("#_=_"); 
   if (idx > 0) { 
     window.location = window.location.toString().substring(0, idx); 
   } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular 2 (RC5) and hash-based routes, I do this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  ...
  {path: '_', redirectTo: '/facebookLoginSuccess'},
  ...
]
```

and

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

As far as I understand, the `=` character in the route is interpreted as part of optional route parameters definition (see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optional-route-parameters), so not involved in the route matching.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and clean solution to remove "#_=_" (PHP):

Instead of "header("Location: xxx.php");" to use "echo ("location.href = 'xxx.php';");"

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for simple answer
Just add this , it worked for me

```
if (window.location.hash === "#_=_"){
    history.replaceState 
        ? history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href.split("#")[0])
        : window.location.hash = "";
}
```

Check the full answer by Paul Schwarz as well

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18305085/2694806

Comment: This is just a copy/paste of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18305085/2694806

Comment: I just add this to reference my self and updated the answer with link to you full answer all credits goes to you @PaulSchwarz I am also referring to your answer and already up voted yours

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vue router with `createWebHistory` history mode (so not hash mode), then you can add the following after you create the router instance (can be done before you `use` it with the app:

```js
router.isReady().then(() => {
  if (router.currentRoute.value.hash === "#_=_") {
    router.replace({ ...router.currentRoute.value, hash: '' })
  }
})
```