# Facebook appends #_=_ callack URL

Tags: php, facebook

After I have changed my getLoginUrl using php SDK with `array('redirect_uri' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'scope' => 'user_about_me')`, still I facing problem with url appending #*=*.

Does anyone have answer for this problem? It happens only in Firefox and Chrome browsers.

Comment: check the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url

Comment: None of the solutions I found were complete enough, so I posted this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18305085/2694806 hope it helps someone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [#\_=\_ added to URL by facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362681/added-to-url-by-facebook)

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with the session redirect behaviour. It was mentioned in the developer blog this week here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/

The comment about it isn't very clear - I would guess they mean if there is no redirect_uri provided, then add this? Check what value you are getting in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: Does not work for me, any idea what is being talked about here