# #_=_ added to URL by facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

After connecting to my Rails app via Facebook I have #_=_ added on to my URL.

I tried specifying a redirect_uri as specified by FB but it didn't work.
Javascript workaround to remove the symbols doesn't help. I tried everything with no results.
Any pointers on how to solve this?

My setup:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
gem "devise", '1.5.2'
gem "omniauth", '1.0.1'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.0.0rc2'

module Facebook
 CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config/facebook.yml"))[Rails.env]
 FB_APP_ID = CONFIG['app_id']
 FB_APP_SECRET = CONFIG['secret_key']
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do    
 provider :facebook, Facebook::FB_APP_ID, Facebook::FB_APP_SECRET,
 :scope => 'offline_access, email, publish_stream',
 :display => 'touch'
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `#_=_` fragment is being intentionally added by Facebook as described under [Change in Sessions Redirect Behavior](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/). Explicitly setting the redirect_uri in your request allegedly takes care of this problem, but there's apparently a bug that persists the unwanted fragment even when the redirect_uri is specified.

Assuming this bug isn't resolved, a workaround may be to replace the hash location using Javascript:

```
window.location.hash = ""
```

This doesn't replace the actual hash character, but will get rid of everything following it.

Comment: thanks zeantsoi. i've been waiting for this but fix but right now i see random effects. i get the #_=_ in chrome but not safari, though before i was getting it in safari too. i'm going with the js workaround for now.

Comment: @tomek — It seems like the best fix will come when Facebook resolves the bug, which is apparently on their to do list. If the explanation and JS workaround is sufficient for now, would you mind voting up or accepting the answer?

Comment: This removed all the characters after the `#`, but the user is presented with the very bottom of the page. Any workaround?

Comment: I'm not experiencing this behavior with jQuery. Are you using a framework, or plain vanilla Javascript? One thing you might try is to add `return false` after `window.location.hash = ""`. This can prevent inner page jumps, but I can't verify this works in your situation because I'm not experiencing the depicted behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is a cleaner answer and the one I used to solve this issue.

You may have # anchors in your URLs that are desirable and this is especially true if you can end up being forwarded to any page on the site after facebook login.  So removing everything in # may cause problems.

This solution will only remove the fubar facebook #*=* string from the URL and leave other parts of the hash intact.

Add this JS to your header or global JS include.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    if (window.location && window.location.hash) {
        if (window.location.hash === '#_=_') {
            window.location.hash = '';
            return;
        }
        var facebookFubarLoginHash = RegExp('_\=_', 'g');
        window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(facebookFubarLoginHash,     '');
    }
}());
```