# PHP Location Header Ignore Hash

Tags: php, header, facebook, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)

I am integrating Facebook login into my site.  When Facebook redirects to my site with the code query parameter, there is a hash at the end `http://myurl.com/code=xxx#_=_`
When I then redirect from this url to another url at my site:

```
header('Location: http://myurl.com/home');
```

It keeps the hash tag and ends up as `http://myurl.com/home#_=_`

Is there a way to redirect without the hash or if anyone is familiar with Facebook a way to get it to stop adding the hash in the first place?

Comment: this is a post for the facebook problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems JavaScript is the only way to remove a hash since the hash is never sent to the server in any way.  So I added a script to a blank page:

```
window.location.hash = '';  window.location.href = "http://myurl.com"
```

This is the answer for now, but I will accept better ones.

Comment: You can set it with the PHP `header`, just include the hash: `header('Location: http://myurl.com/home#');`

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect on your server side PHP to a URL that includes its own hash. That's what I had to do a ruby app that uses backbone.js.

PS - I specified the `redirect_uri` and FB still appended the stupid `#_=_` string :/