# Header location not working properly

Tags: php, header

My URL is http://www.website.ro/index.php?subiect=10046&pag=1**#1006**, and i have a form here with no action (`<form action="" method="post">`).

After submit I'm checking some input fields and if there is any error, I want to redirect. I use this code:

```
header('Location: /index.php?subiect='.$_GET['subiect'].'&pag='.$_GET['pag']); exit();
```

But the redirect includes **#1006** so my page becomes http://www.website.ro/index.php?subiect=10046&pag=1**#1006**

I tried to change location in the header with:

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com'); exit();
```

The page where takes me is : http://www.google.com**#1006**

Why does it do this?

I have `ob_start()` at first line and i tried to deleted it. No effect. The url after redirect stil has **#1006**.

If my url is http://www.website.ro/index.php?subiect=10046&pag=1 and i use header location i don't have problems, but if the url contains #1006 the url after redirect contains to.

Comment: looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338853/php-location-header-ignore-hash it looks like you can't remove the hash from PHP, you have to clear it using javascript first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part after the `#` is called the *fragment identifier* and identifies a part of the page, even if the page is retrieved from another URL.

By default most browsers keep the fragment identifier when a 3xx redirect occurs, regardless of what status code is used. See [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects) for several resources about the matter.

You can return an URI that contains a fragment identifier itself (even an empty one):

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com/#');
```

Then that one will be used instead, as specified in [this draft](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Fragment/draft-bos-http-redirect-00.txt):

> The exception is when a returned URI already has a fragment
>   identifier. In that case the original fragment identifier MUST NOT be
>   not added to it.

You could also change the fragment identifier `onclick` using Javascript.

Comment: He could probably specify a dummy/empty fragment during the redirect

Comment: @AlexandruCretu You can't use javascript because, If javascript is disabled what can you do?