# 301 Redirect without fragment

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, uri, fragment-identifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)

I need to help regarding the 301 Redirect without Special character.

For example, I want to redirect the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/iphone-ipad-mobile-apps-portfolio.html#Gigguid
```

To the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/portfolio.html
```

I have changed `.htaccess` to perform the redirect, but the fragment `#Gigguid` remains in the final URL. How can this be fixed?

Comment: What does redirect with special character mean?

Comment: Which special character is not working for you? The `#`? That has a special meaning, the server won't get to see that

Comment: show me your .htaccess file

Answer (score 3):

The current HTTP standard does not allow you to do such a redirect - at least the HTTP client is refusing to do so. Your browser will always add the `#...` part to the redirect URI.

This `#....` is called *Fragement* by the way, special character is not saying much (a URI has many special characters like `:`, `%`, `?` and `&`), better use the right name for this.

The next HTTP standard release will likely take care of that issue but it's still a bit fragile, the meaning has changed sometimes in the draft and as I can not look into the future it's yet too early how this will be done with the next stable release of HTTP.

See as well this question for more information:

- [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2286402/367456)
- [PHP Location Header Ignore Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7338853/367456)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code in `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)-(.*)\.(html|htm|php)$
RewriteRule ^ /%2.%3 [R=301,L]
```

sample :

```
http://www.example.com/iphone-ipad-mobile-apps-portfolio.html?id=3#Gigguid
```

redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/portfolio.html?id=3#Gigguid
```

Comment: The OP wants to _remove_ the fragment identifier, not preserve it, as in your example. This is what's happening by default.