# How to clear fragment identifier on 302 redirect?

Tags: http, url, redirect, http-redirect, fragment-identifier

It seems that after a 302 direct, the browser preserves the fragment identifier:

```
/foo#/bar/baz
```

returns 302 to `/login`, but browser shows:

```
/login#/bar/baz
```

How do I get the browser to redirect and clear the fragment so it just shows:

```
/login
```

Comment: This would have been a duplicate (but it’s closed as duplicate itself): [301 Redirect without fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14477154/1591669)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if the server adds '#' to the end of the redirect URL it will override any existing fragment. Of course, the redirect URL must tolerate an empty fragment, but if so, the redirect header can simply be:

> Location /login#

Works for me.