# PHP Header redirect to not keep hash value

Tags: php

I'm navigating away from a page that has a URL similar to

```
http://solo.dev/module-1/behavioural-safety/?id=7#14
```

by using

```
if($course_id != $_GET['id']) {
    header("location: /courses/");
}
```

However, it persists the #14 value as

```
http://solo.dev/courses/#14
```

How do I redirect to just `/courses/` without retaining the hashed value?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify **empty hash** instead:

```
header("location: /courses/#");
```

Then, on `courses/` site you check if there's an empty hash and remove it using JavaScript:

```
history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work
as simple as that,

```
header('location: /courses#');
```

for empty hash you can do this,

```
window.location.hash = '';
window.location.href = "http://yoururl.com"
```

Comment: I don't want a hash value, even an empty hash, ideally my URL would be http://solo.dev/courses/ and not http://solo.dev/courses/#

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338853/php-location-header-ignore-hash