# Facebook appending #_=_ to the redirect url

Tags: php, facebook

When I am trying to connect using the Facebook Connect SDK for PHP, #_=_ is appended to the URL. As a result of this, subsequent calls to facebook don't work. How to take care of this.

Does any one have an answer to question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [#\_=\_ added to URL by facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362681/added-to-url-by-facebook)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Callback appends '#\_=\_' to Return URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url)

Answer (score 1):

This fragment is to do with your redirect_uri and you need to make your app be able to handle it. See here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/