# Rails Delete Resource Identifier on Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, jquery-mobile

I have a project using jQuery Mobile (uses resource identifier heavily) with Facebook authentication. Recently Facebook started adding `#_=_` to callbacks (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url)). This is killing jQuery Mobile.

Is it possible to do an automatic redirect for any routes matching `#_=_` to the stripped counterpart? Is it possible to specify a resource identifier (#) when doing a redirect to? Any other possible fixes? I currently use a javascript redirect but this causes duplicate page loads and issues with some of the analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added in the following work around until Facebook fixes it (seems to work):

```
# app/controllers/omniauth_controller.rb

def create
  ...
  js_redirect_to(user_path)
end

private

def js_redirect_to(path)
  @location = path
  render "shared/redirect"
end

# app/views/shared/redirect.html.haml

:javascript
  window.location = '#{@location}'
```