# Remove '#_=_' from the Facebook redirect URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

According to https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/ the FB Graph API now appends a `_=_` hash to the end of the URL it redirects back to when `redirect_uri` is not set. However, it is still appending it even though my call specifies the `redirect_uri`.

Short of redirecting again after FB returns to my site, how can I get FB to stop appending the hash?

PS - the hash is breaking backbone.js and I need it gone. This isn't just a pet peeve.

Comment: what have you specified the redirect_uri as?

Comment: check here : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7338853/php-location-header-ignore-hash/7340855#7340855 and here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/7131909/720508 , i think the only way to resolve this now is through javascript

Comment: Thanks, I answered my Q so others can see how I dealt with the issue for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/196125357123225

Apparently the Facebook Graph API documentation is incorrect and a bug has been submitted. Sad face.

My hack fix was to override the redirect on the server side and replace the hash with my own so that the FB hash was not included in the redirect(in ruby).

Comment: Just noticed this myself. My test page is just entering an infinite redirect loop. Has Facebook said anything past their "We're triaging this" comments?

Comment: Brenden>  can you post the code snippet you used to override the redirect?

Comment: Why is my answer down voted to -2? @GeorgeW, I don't ahve the code currently, but it wasn't too hard. Just detect the hash and redirect with your own hashed URL

Comment: @Brenden  stumbled upon this post again and saw your comment. I just want to make it clear that I never down vote your answer. In general, a code snippet is more than a thousand words.  For example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362681/added-to-url-by-facebook

Comment: @GeorgeW I never thought you did :) Point taken re:code snippets. PS - let's continue this convo in a year :D

Comment: It does the same thing for google omniauth, so I get an error no route matches, it appends # (hashtag) after request uri   https://.....herokuapp.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=19feaacfe23423jh5jhhGSDFwb419049ebb18dabdf8&code=4/glrY3-mSlTzwerwERTEG334eXcn3hOSxGuc51BAlglPa4AU#