# How to remove ugly characters from URl after FacebookOmniauth login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm using omniauth-facebook gem and it works well.

But when it loads back the page on the application it adds these characters to the url:

```
/#_=_
```

How can I stop this from happening.

NOOB

Comment: You can’t. Only thing you can do is try to redirect to the same URL without the hash part, or setting it to blank using `location.hash` in JavaScript.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693663/remove-from-the-facebook-redirect-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.location.hash == '#_=_')window.location.hash = ''; //this script removes the #_=_ from the url which is appended by facebook after login
</script>
```

Comment: This kinda works. However it still leaves  the '#' instead of empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.hash=="#_=_") window.location.href="http://yourdomain.com/";
</script>
```