# Jquery mobile page won't load after facebook authentication in chrome

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I'm running into a strange interaction between chrome and jquery mobile.  The application flow is straightforward:

- Homepage / login screen.  "Login" link is `data-ajax="false"` and `rel="external"` so all the fancy JQM AJAX stuff is disabled.
- A series of 302s for the oauth dance which ends at `/auth/facebook/callback`
- `/auth/facebook/callback` 302s to the real page `/home` which is a very simple Jquery-mobile page

On Chrome and Firefox the jquery mobile 'ajax-loading' spinner shows forever, with the actual page loaded in the DOM but not displaying.  On Safari (desktop or mobile) the page displays properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from Facebook.  When returning from oauth, they add a URL fragment `#_=_` to your callback URL, which confuses JQM.  As is typical for FB, this is [documented](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/) as deliberate without justification but vague/incorrect instructions for how to deal with it.  A bunch of discussion in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url).  The best workaround I found is to insert this code to the top of your page before JQM has a chance to get confused:

```
<script>
    // workaround Facebook oauth feature-bug
    if (window.location.hash == '#_=_') window.location.hash = '';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, AJAX requests don't handle redirects very well (there are tons of SO questions about this subject).

Instead of doing your authentication in JavaScript, how about a server-side implementation? It will be faster and less complicated for the user's browser.

Comment: Fair suggestion for a workaround.  But the request is not AJAX -- I turned that off.  It's a brand new complete page being loaded in the browser after a redirect.