# Grails redirect and spring security

Tags: grails, redirect, spring-security

Calling a redirect inside a controller action always add a strange fragment to the redirect url.

Grails 2.1.0

```
def index = {
   ...
   //Spring security programmatic authentication
   ...
  redirect(uri: '/me')
}
```

Whill redirect the browser to /me#_=_

Tried to alter the redirect adding

```
redirect(uri: '/me', fragment:null)
```

or

```
redirect(uri: '/me', absolute:true)
```

don't change the result

where that #_=_ came from????

Comment: Is it just a vanilla grails install with only the Spring Security plugin added? You really haven't given enough information to figure out what's going on.

Comment: It's a bug on Facebook Connect [found this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url