# How to remove Angular JS Route "#_=_" when redirecting to application route (via rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, angularjs

I have a rails action that redirect to the root of my application but angular seems to add `#_=_` to the route.

I can't see why this is being added.  It doesn't cause any harm, but it doesn't look professional.

Wondering how I can avoid having this appended to the root.

Note: Only added after redirect.  Visiting root directly does not append.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url

Comment: Fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url/26935709#26935709

Answer (score 4):

This is added by facebook not by angular