# Why do i have characters "#_=_" appended in my URL after logging in from facebook into my App

Tags: codeigniter, url, facebook-graph-api, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Callback appends ‘#_=_’ to Return URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url)

Well its not an problem that i am facing since its not mixing up in any way with my code, but just an curiosity to know why the URL of my app gets appended by this extra characters as #*=*  when user logs into my site using Facebook api ?

For eg my url should be

```
 www.xyz.com/viewResume
```

but it actually is

```
 www.xyz.com/viewResume#_=_
```

Any particular reason for this behaviour ?
Am using Codeigniter Framework

Comment: I posted my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18305085/2694806

Answer (score 3):

I forget why it does it, I searched for a while too but it's just remnants of the return URL FB posts if I remember right. It's pretty easy to make go away with a little js on the page that you send users back to after login though.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
    if (window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
        window.location.hash = ''; // for older browsers, leaves a # behind
        history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname); // nice and clean
        e.preventDefault(); // no page reload
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why that `e.preventDefault();`? It's giving me errors (e not defined).

Comment: eh, I left out the function bit sorry. Fixed.