# Facebook Authentication Error with Rails, Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, facebook-authentication

I am using Omniauth gem to provide Facebook authentication in my app, but the url, with which Facebook redirects user is `http://localhost:3000/users/login#_=_`, this happens right after the user enters its email/password. I don't know whats causing it, Google seems to be working fine.

```
         Omniauth Callback
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

      def all
        user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
        if user.persisted?
          flash.notice = "Signed in!"
          sign_in_and_redirect user
        else
          session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
      # alias_method :twitter, :all
      alias_method :facebook, :all
      alias_method :google_oauth2, :all
    end



      Routes.rb
devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
  controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}



     User.rb
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
  end
end
def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  if session["devise.user_attributes"]
    new(session["devise.user_attributes"]) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: actually this is how it should be, in my app it works same and no trouble here, if you mean `#_=_`, this is not issue

Comment: If you want to remove `_=_` check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7297873/1297435)

Comment: ok.. Why does it link back to my login page? the authentication callback seems to work fine for twitter and google.

Comment: @user2206030, provide more code, where do you redirect authenticated user

Comment: @user2206030, sign_in_and_redirect user - code of this method?

Comment: I think its a method generated by devise.