# Facebook Login with #_=_ behind URL

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-4

Facebook Login

```
  // Get the page we were before
  $redirect = Session::get('loginRedirect', 'hirer/account');
```

The domain became this

```
 http://domain.com/hirer/account#_=_
```

What is the #*=* behind how do i not display it?

Comment: try updating laravel.

Comment: Yes they append it after redirecting from Facebook. There doesn't seem to be a way to remove it from your PHP/Laravel code. But you can remove it using Javascript like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7297873/783875

Comment: @WebNovice Thanks, please set that as your answer :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although this thread is old, but hope this might help someone else.
I have seen some people resolve the problem by adding javascript code to the redirected page to remove the #_=_ from the location.

However, that is ugly for me. There is another way of solving this issue from back-end. You can make your redirect url to contains the your own anchor # so that it will overwrite the #_=_ added by facebook. For example, this is my Laravel's handleProviderCallback:

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();
    // add the user to your database if it doesn't exist

    // redirect the user to home page, the anchor # is 
    // to overwrite #_=_ anchor added by facebook
    return redirect('/#');
}
```

Comment: Works great for me, I don't mind the anchor being a single hash... the underscores just made it look like a bug!

Answer (score 2):

Yes they append it after redirecting from Facebook. There doesn't seem to be a way to remove it from your PHP/Laravel code.

But you can remove it using Javascript like here: 
[stackoverflow.com/a/7297873/783875](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7297873/783875)