# Wierd text: "#_=_" showing on the URL after successful Login to Facebook with spring social

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, backbone.js, spring-social

```
http://X.com:8080/X/#_=_
```

This is the  URL that i am getting after successful login

I cant seem to catch these characters with backbone.js as well so i dont really understand how to overcome this.

Anyone has any idea why this could happen?

> ```
>     <org.springframework.social-version>1.1.0.M1</org.springframework.social-version>
>     <org.springframework.social.facebook-version>1.1.0.M1</org.springframework.social.facebook-version>
> ```

And the call to the server (using handlebars you can imagine what provider sais):

> ```
>  <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="provider-login-btn-template">
>     <form action="signin/{{provider}}" method="POST" class="form" style="margin:0px">
>         <fieldset>
>             <div class="formRow">
>                 <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email,publish_stream,offline_access" />    
>                 <input type="image" style="width:50px;height:50px" src="{{image_url}}" onsubmit="submit();" />
>             </div>
>         </fieldset>
>     </form>
> </script>
> ```

Thats it. i am redirected to facebook, login, then back to `/#_=_` .

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Callback appends '#\_=\_' to Return URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url)

Answer (score 1):

A very hacky way to do this is to just accept the garbage that Facebook is appending to the redirect_uri, and alias that in your backbone router.  For example, in my application, users are redirected to http://www.exampleapp.com/# on successful authentication, which will match the Backbone route I had established:

```
ExampleApp.Routers.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  ...
  routes: {
    "": "index",
  },
  ...
});
```

The problem with what Facebook was doing was that the " _ = _ " at the end of window.href breaks the Backbone router.  So the hacky way I dealt with this was to *simply stop fighting* and alias the junk to **also** match the index method, as follows:

```
ExampleApp.Routers.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  ...
  routes: {
    "": "index",
    "_=_": "index"
  },
  ...
});
```

Then, in the "index" method (or whatever you've called it), add something like the following to make the url prettier:

```
if (window.location.hash === "#_=_") {
    window.location.hash = "#";
}
```

Now, obviously there will be more complex situations where this will not work, so I write this answer with no warranty!

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand ConnectController class from spring social.

You can redirect to another URL with overriding connectionStatusRedirect method.

Ex.

```
@Override
protected RedirectView connectionStatusRedirect(String providerId, NativeWebRequest request) {
    String path = "http://X.com:8080/X/facebookRedirect";

    return new RedirectView(path, true);
}
```