# How to prevent ASP.NET Identity external login from adding a # to end of url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin

Normally it wouldn't be a big deal, but I'm building an AngularJS app, and the # added by ASP.NET's Identity external login (OWIN based) is wreaking havoc on the angularjs app.

You can see it even on a default new C# ASP.NET MVC site with Google uncommented in Startup.Auth.cs.

A # gets added to the end of the url when a user is logged in and redirected. I've tried handling this redirection on my own, but to no avail... a hash tag always gets added.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

The default solution uses a form to initiate the external login, like so:

```
using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id="socialLoginList">
        <p>
        @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
        {
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
        }
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

I don't see anything in that adding a # to request.

If you look at the Login action, you'll see it calls its own private method to handle redirect:

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl) {
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Even when `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` is hit it has a # at the end of the url.

I've tried hard coding the return like so: `return Redirect("/home/index");` but that also still has the # at the end.

**Update 2**
Looks like it only happens in Chrome.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a link button or similar control doing the login? The solution might be as simple as adding `return false;` to the end of the `onclick` event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url

Comment: Actually, it looks like it only does it in Chrome. ;(

Answer (score 2):

### The short answer

**You cannot as far as I know.**

I've had the exact same issue (though in all browsers, not just Chrome). When I investigated I found the hash is hard coded in the [OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.ApplyResponseGrantAsync](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs) method, with the following code

```
var appender = new Appender(location, '#');
appender
    .Append(Constants.Parameters.AccessToken, accessToken)
    .Append(Constants.Parameters.TokenType, Constants.TokenTypes.Bearer);
```

### The longer answer

Campaign to to get it changed, please vote up the issue I've raised: **[Provide a mechanism to choose the hash '#' separator when redirecting after an external login](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/204).**

### The workaround

I've worked around the issue by choosing a landing page that isn't an AngularJS app which converts the # to a Hashbang `#!`. Here is the page I've used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>window.location.replace('/#!/' + window.location.hash);</script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Please wait.</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>Please wait.</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but what I can't understand is *why* this is being appended.