# Remove fragment identifier (hash parameter) in Play! 2.3.x

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have implemented Facebook log in in my Play application. However, the Facebook OAuth callback url have a mysterious `#_=_` fragment identifier appended. It was described in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url).

The fragment identifier have stayed in the URL after I redirect the user to another pages. How can I have it removed in a `Controller`?

Comment: My workaround for this situation was to append "#/" (pointing to react.js root) to URL used for redirection. I have no idea whether it is browser or server persisting this fragment but setting new fragment overrides the facebook one.