# Facebook connect wit hoauth in Yii return address to localhost

Tags: facebook, yii, authorization

This question is for users who know  hoauth of yii 
I'm using hoauth extension with Yii to log users.

If the user is already connected to Facebook, then after login,  he is redirect to localhost

If the user is not connected to Facebook,  then,  the facebook login page is shown and when the user identified to facebook, he is redirected to his profile page of my application.

Question: which parameter should I change to redirect him to his profile page when he is already connected to facebook.

Comment: Hi klark , you can redirect him by checking whether user is loggedin or not . There is an option in SDK , which returns Facebook Id , you can use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  ramamoothly   ,   I found the solution in post [Facebook Callback appends '#_=_' to Return URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url)

which is not related with Yii  but gives a good overview of the mechanism