# Response.Redirect appends #_=_ at the end of the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I am using Response.Redirect in my ASP.NEt to redirect to the same page but with a different query string. However, when the page redirects, for some reasons unknown, this hash `#_=_` is being added to the page.

Here's the redirect code in C#:

```
Response.Redirect("~/signup/?type=facebookregistration");
 return;
```

What causes this?

Comment: What is the redirected page name?

Comment: Are you using any javascript library that manipulates the `window.location` object such as `Angular JS`?

Comment: @Leo No. only jQuery. When I load the page regurally, it's ok, just when I redirect it happens.

Comment: @un-lucky the same name is the one that I am redirecting to

Comment: are you using any third-party OAuth authentication scheme? Such as Facebook, LinkedIn, etc.?

Comment: @Leo, yes Facebook login and Google login code also

Comment: @IdanShechter `Response.Redirect` should not append `#_=_` by default. Could you able to replicate the issue in a brand new asp.net application with least amount of code?

Comment: @Win, yes, I will do that now.

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url) with big count of answers and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticating with Facebook includes an optional url fragment...`redirect_uri`, when this fragment is left blank, then the empty fragment `#_=_` is appended.
They actually mention it in this post

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/

If this affects the behaviour of your application you can easily remove using javascript

Comment: First of all thanks for finding it. I put a data in the redirect_uri when I call the faceobok api. I don't understand why calling a redirection and reloading the page makes it appear. Maybe I just don't understand what Session redirect is :)