# Redirect to "next" after python-social-auth login

Tags: django, python-social-auth

In my settings.py I have the following:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'Eapp:login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'Eapp:logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'Eapp:login'
```

And in my template I've got the following

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{request.path}}">
```

Next takes it to the correct url but it's followed by `#_=_` Which is what I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
?next={{request.path}}
```

and

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ='/your_url' without 'Eapp:'

i hope, this help you

Comment: What if `next` is dynamic?