# #_=_ at the end of url after facebook login

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, loopbackjs

I am using loopback and passport to get facebook authentication for my app. This seems to be working correctly. The user gets redirected to fb for login and then back to my app. However, for some reason there seems to be a `#_=_` appended to the url of my app. Any Ideas what could be causing this?

This is actually also happening on couchsurfing.com for me. I have tried different browsers and computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Facebook returns a URL including `#_=_`, during the OAuth authentication handshake.

Comment: Why does it do this? I am not seeing this issue with other providers(twitter etc).

Comment: Found my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41917323/3761234