# How do I write a RewriteRule for a url contains a hashtag

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I used Facebook social login for my website and when it happens in the final step facebook redirects to my website with a appended ID. So my URL looks like below.`https://example.com/#_=_`. I need to remove this and redirect to my website without this hash ID.

Need to do this in the htaccess. But everything I've tried failed.

Below I've tried.

```
RewriteRule ^#_=_(.*)$ https://example.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^#_=_()$ https://example.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You don’t, because you simply _can’t_ … The fragment portion of the URL does not get send to the server in the first place.

Comment: Its not nice to have something like this in the url :(

Comment: Well then you’ll have to remove it on the client side, using JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facebook Callback appends '#\_=\_' to Return URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url)