# URL address changing from localhost:3000/home to localhost:3000/home#_=_

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport-facebook

I configured my project first with passport-google-oauth20 authentication and it was working fine.
I added the passport-facebook after that and its working fine as well, however, after logging/registering with my FB account my redirecting URI which is supposed to be "http://localhost:3000/home" shows "http://localhost:3000/home#*=*" instead. It isn't showing any errors in the console and also working as it is intended to. I've got no clue what part of code I'm suppose to share with you guys as the functionality of the project is intact, so please let me know the snippet which may help you to better understand the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41917323/1427878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem itself.

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#why-is-__-appended-to-the-redirect-uri