# Why do some websites include #_=_ at the end of a URL?

Tags: url, analytics

Some websites like Facebook and Ask FM use `#_=_` at the end of an URL to an external website. Why?

If two large websites are doing so, surely it must mean something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is after authenticating with Facebook. The base path becomes a hash which eventually breaks the navigation.

I think this is because of facebook passing the url with some hash key. Because with or without passing redirection url facebook passing this to avoid vulnerability of attacks.

From https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/, change in Session Redirect Behavior:
This week, we started adding a fragment #*=* to the redirect_uri when this field is left blank. Please ensure that your app can handle this behavior.

A solution is simply removing the hash as stated here then everything seems back to normal:

[Facebook Callback appends '#_=_' to Return URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url)